# the only solution of prime $q|(p^2-1)$ with $p<q$ is $p=2$ and $q=3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I am trying to prove a lemma that the only solution of $q|(p^2-1)$ with $p<q$ is $p=2$ and $q=3$.

i.e if $p<q$ are primes and $q|(p^2-1)$, then $p=2$ and $q=3$.

Since $q|(p^2-1)$, then $q|(p+1)$ or $q|(p-1)$. Since $p<q$, we have only $q|(p+1)$. But I am not sure if $q|(p^2-1)$ implies $q|(p+1)$ or $q|(p-1)$, since $p<q,$ we have $q|(p+1)$. But I got stuck here.

Comment: $p^2-1=(p+1)(p-1)$,  but if $p>2$ then $p+1$ can't be prime, so any prime factor of it must be $<p$.

Comment: It does not necessarily imply $q|(p+1)$ or $q|(p-1)$ as you can see for many numbers. It of course holds true here but a better and more obvious logic to go by is what @lulu said.

Comment: To stress:  Euclid's Lemma tells us that, for primes $q$, $q\,|\,ab\implies q\,|\,a$ or $q\,|\,b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I swear I have seen this exact question a few moments ago, but here goes nothing:

$$q\mid(p^2-1)=(p-1)(p+1)\implies q\mid (p-1) \text{ or } q \mid (p+1)$$

the above is a basic property of primes.

We have $q \mid (p-1) \implies p-1\ge q$. But $p<q\le p-1$ is a contradiction.

Therefore we must have $q\mid (p+1)$.

This implies $p+1 \ge q$, which combined with $q>p$, forces $q=p+1$.

Since $p,q$ are primes, $p = 2$, $q=3$.

Comment: lol. I guess it was me who posted the question in which, however, I ask different things. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: by the way, you are really impressive. You got 10 in the past 21 hours as a new contributor.

Comment: @xyz Let's just say I use this site to procrastinate.